# uibutton sender tag

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a UIImageView object that when clicked it will play a animation, I want to reuse the same code to make multiple objects.  How do I set the sender tag so it knows its a different object?

.h

```
- (IBAction)startClick:(id)sender;
```

.m

```
- (IBAction)startClick:(id)sender
{
    //UIImageView *theButton = (UIImageView *)sender.tag;

    bubble.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [UIImage imageNamed: @"Pop_1.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed: @"Pop_2.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed: @"Pop_3.png"], nil];

    [bubble setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    bubble.animationDuration = 1;
    [bubble startAnimating];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Casting sender parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089752/casting-sender-parameter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sender is the object that called the startClick method.  You can cast that object into a UIImageView and then look at that object's tag property to determine which one it is.

You'll need to set the tag property elsewhere in the code.  If you have the UIImageViews in Interface Builder, you can use the properties window to enter a tag number.  Otherwise, when you allocate and init your UIImageViews, set the tag property then.

Answer (score 17):

Use `[sender tag]`.

Why not `sender.tag`, you ask?

You can only use the dot notation if you cast `sender` as an instance of `UIView`, as in `((UIView *)sender).tag`. Objects of `UIView` have a tag property. If you don't cast `sender` as an instance of `UIView`, it is just an `id` that conforms to the `NSURLAuthenticationChallengeSender` protocol, and it lacks a `tag` property.

Here's an example of using a button's tag:

```
#define kButtonTag  2

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   // ... view setup ...

   UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   // ... button setup ...

   button.tag = kButtonTag;

   [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)startClicked:(id)sender {

   if ([sender tag] == kButtonTag) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is so much faster than casting the sender to the appropriate class/object first then getting the tag from it!!!!

Comment: just a quick question about the above code: What does the "#define kButtonTag 2" line of code do?